# Always use neg[.z.w] to ensure that all messages are asynchronous?

Tags: kdb

Consider the following definition on server:

```
f:{show "Received ",string x; neg[.z.w] (`mycallback; x+1)}
```

on client side:

```
q)mycallback:{show "Returned ",string x;}
q)neg[h] (`f; 42)
q)"Returned 43"
```

In the `q for motrtals`, the tip says:

> When performing asynchronous messaging, always use neg[.z.w] to ensure
>   that all messages are asynchronous. Otherwise you will get a deadlock
>   as each process waits for the other.

therefore I change the definition on the server as:

```
f:{show "Received ",string x; .z.w (`mycallback; x+1)}
```

everything goes fine, and I haven't seen any deadlocks.

Can anyone give me an example to show why I should always use `neg[.z.w]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you're question correctly I think your asking how sync and async messages work. The issue with the example you have provided is that x+1 is a very simple query that can be evaluated almost instantaneously. For a more illustrative example consider changing this to a sleep (or a more strenuous calculation, eg. a large database query).

On your server side define:

```
f:{show "Received ",string x;system "sleep 10"; neg[.z.w] (`mycallback; x+1)}
```

Then on your client side you can send the synchronous query:

```
h(`f; 42)
```

multiple times. Doing this you will see there is no longer a q prompt on the client side as it must wait for a response. These requests can be queued and thus block both the client and server for a significant amount of time.

Alternatively, if you were to call:

```
(neg h)(`f; 42)
```

on the client side. You will see the q prompt remain, as the client is not waiting for a response. This is an asynchronous call.

Now, in your server side function you are looking at using either .z.w or neg .z.w. This follows the exact same principal however from a server perspective. If the response to query is large enough, the messaging can take a significant amount of time. Consequently, by using neg this response can be sent asynchronously so the server is not blocked during this process.

NOTE: If you are working on a windows machine you will need to swap out sleep for timeout or perhaps a while loop if you are following my examples.

Update:  I suppose one way to cause such a deadlock would be to have two dependant processes, attempting to synchronously call each other. For example:

```
q)\p 10002
q)h:hopen 10003
q)g:{h (`f1;`)}
q)h (`f;`)'
```

on one side and

```
q)\p 10003
q)h:hopen 10002
q)f:{h (`g;`)}
q)f1:{show "test"}
```

on the other. This would result in both processes being stuck and thus test never being shown.

Comment: I dont understand your last sentence. Yes, I am using windows, should I use `\t timeout 10` or something?

Comment: and actually, I am asking why a **deadlock** happens if I dont use a `neg .z.w`, any examples on this?

Comment: @buzhidao Firstly, for the sleep alternative you can use `2_system["timeout 3"]`. On your second point of deadlock, I don't think this means a literal deadlock but simply that, for example, a client could be waiting for a response with no q prompt due to a long process running on the server side. This can be seen in my example, where the sync request must wait for the sleep on the server side to progress.This can be seen in my example, where the sync request must wait for the sleep on the server side to progress. This could cause a 'deadlock' if there was, for example, an infinite loop.

Comment: I've added a new update to this reply so the code is formatted properly, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Joe's answer covers pretty much everything, but to your specific example, a deadlock happens if the client calls

```
h (`f; 42)
```

Client is waiting response from the server before processing the next request, but the server is also waiting response from the client before it completes the client's request.